# Changing RabbitMQ Server in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, symfony-3.4

The company I work for is currently in the process of changing the sever in which we have RabbitMQ on. We are using Symfony, with the `php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle` bundle, and trying to move producers and consumers modularly by changing the `connection` property in the configuration.

Unfortunately we have roughly 180 queues, and for each one we change, we need to do a cache:clear which at the moment for us means downtime. I'm wondering if anyone has had to do this before, and knows how we can migrate the consumers across without doing a cache:clear each time.

So far we've just been trying the `php bin/console rabbitmq:setup-fabric` command which hasn't been changing anything due to the cache.

If we could do a partial `cache:clear` for just that rabbit stuff that would be ideal, but I'm unsure if this is possible/how to do it in Symfony (we're using 3.4 for reference).

Any help would be great, please feel free to ask for any more info. TIA :)

Comment: Is this a code-related question or a server/network administration question? I don't see that there is any code or programming involved here.

Comment: Well it's a more of a config question, I'm happy to send a snapshot of our configuration if that helps